# Route guarding using Firebase Authentication and Ngrx

Tags: firebase, redux, firebase-authentication, angular-routing, ngrx

**Correctly validate authentication status using Ngrx store**

I need to validate if the user is authenticated when I access some route of my application by checking the store for the authentication state of the user.

When I access a route and the `CanActivate()` method is called, I have verified that the authentication state is the initial state set, I need the authentication status changed with the authenticated user if it is.

In the `CanActivate()` method I tried calling the `GetUser()` action before making the select checking whether the user is authenticated or not but this is not working properly.

Below is the code for how I am performing validation.

My application uses the **Firebase Authentication** service so I have a method in my authentication service that returns the authentication state of the user.

```
getUsuario(): Observable<firebase.User> {
    return this._angularFireAuth.authState;
}
```

**auth.state.ts:**

```
import { createFeatureSelector, createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as fromAuth from '../reducers/auth.reducer';

export interface AuthState {
    userData: any; // firebase user models
    isLoggedIn: boolean;
    error: any;
    loading?: boolean;
    loaded: boolean;
}

export const authInitialState: AuthState = {
    userData: null,
    isLoggedIn: false,
    error: null,
    loaded: false,
};

export const getAuthState = createFeatureSelector<AuthState>('auth');

export const getAuthUserData = createSelector(getAuthState, fromAuth.getUserData);
export const getAuthIsLoggedIn = createSelector(getAuthState, fromAuth.getIsUserLoggedIn);
export const getAuthError = createSelector(getAuthState, fromAuth.getError);
```

**auth.reducer.ts:**

```
import { AuthActions, ActionsTypes } from '../actions/auth.actions';
import { AuthState, authInitialState } from '../states/auth.state';

export function reducer(
    state = authInitialState, action: AuthActions): AuthState {

switch (action.type) {

    case ActionsTypes.GET_USER: {
        return {
            ...state,
            loaded: false,
            loading: true
        };
    }

    case ActionsTypes.AUTHENTICATED:
        return {
            ...state,
            userData: action.payload,
            loaded: true,
            loading: false,
            isLoggedIn: true
        };

    case ActionsTypes.NOT_AUTHENTICATED:
        return {
            ...state,
            ...authInitialState,
            loaded: true,
            loading: false,
            isLoggedIn: false
        };

    case ActionsTypes.LOGIN_EMAIL_PASSWORD:
        return {
            ...state,
            loading: true
        };

    case ActionsTypes.AUTH_ERROR:
        return {
            ...state,
            ...action.payload,
            loading: false
        };

    case ActionsTypes.LOGOUT:
        return {
            ...state,
            loading: true
        };

    default: {
        return state;
    }
}

}

export const getUserData = (state: AuthState) => state.userData;
export const getIsUserLoggedIn = (state: AuthState) => state.isLoggedIn;
export const getError = (state: AuthState) => state.error;
```

**auth.effects.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

// Services
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

// RxJS
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { map, switchMap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

// NGRX
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Actions, Effect } from '@ngrx/effects';
import * as authActions from '../actions/auth.actions';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthEffects {
    constructor(
        private _router: Router,
        private _authService: AuthService,
        private _actions$: Actions,
    ) { }


    @Effect()
    getUser: Observable<Action> = this._actions$.ofType(authActions.ActionsTypes
        .GET_USER).pipe(
            map((action: authActions.GetUser) => action.payload),
            switchMap(() => this._authService.getUsuario()),
            map(user => {
                if (user) {
                    const usuario = {
                        uid: user.uid,
                        email: user.email,
                        displayName: user.displayName
                    };
                    return new authActions.Authenticated(usuario);
                } else {
                    this._router.navigate(['auth/login']);
                    return new authActions.NotAuthenticated();
                }
            })
        );

    @Effect()
    loginEmailPassword: Observable<Action> = this._actions$.ofType(authActions.ActionsTypes
        .LOGIN_EMAIL_PASSWORD).pipe(
            map((action: authActions.LoginEmailPassword) => action.payload),
            switchMap(usuario => this._authService
                .loginWithEmailAndPassword(usuario.email, usuario.password).pipe(
                    map(() => {
                        this._router.navigate(['']);
                        return new authActions.GetUser();
                    }),
                    catchError((err => of(new authActions.AuthError({ error: err }))))
                ))
        );

    @Effect()
    logout: Observable<Action> = this._actions$.ofType(authActions.ActionsTypes
        .LOGOUT).pipe(
            map((action: authActions.Logout) => action.payload),
            switchMap(() => this._authService.logout().pipe(
                map(() => {
                    this._router.navigate(['auth/login']);
                    return new authActions.NotAuthenticated();
                }),
                catchError((err => of(new authActions.AuthError({ error: err }))))
            ))
        );

    @Effect()
    reautenticaUsuario: Observable<Action> = this._actions$.ofType(authActions.ActionsTypes
        .REAUTHENTICATE).pipe(
            map((action: authActions.Reauthenticate) => action.payload.password),
            switchMap(password => this._authService
                .reauthenticateUsuario(password).pipe(
                    map(() => new authActions.ReauthenticateSuccess()),
                    catchError((err => of(new authActions.AuthError({ error: err }))))
                ))
        );

}
```

**auth.guard.ts:**

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    this._store.dispatch(new fromAuth.GetUser());
    return this._store.select(getAuthIsLoggedIn);
}
```

Comment: Look here [Preloading ngrx/store with Route Guards](https://toddmotto.com/preloading-ngrx-store-route-guards)

Comment: I've been trying to run this way, but it's in an infinite loop and nothing happens.

Comment: did you find your answer? Could you share it? I'm interested to get the answer too. thanks